# Iterative mysql queries slowing down

Tags: mysql, performance

I did a quick set of queries to break this:  `27JAN2013` into `2013-01-27` in another field. It was easier just to do 12 in a row changing the month to be written for each.  What I noticed is each subsequent query took a little bit longer.

The first:

```
update 
   hondaacura 
set transdate1 = concat_ws('-',substr(trxdate,6,4),'01', left(trxdate,2)) 
where substr(trxdate,3,3) = 'JAN';
```

It took 6.27 to update on a total table size of 3.5 million records.

The February statement running next took 6.9, and so on, until December which took 12.3.

Why would it slow down with each subsequent query?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by - "It was easier just to do 12 in a row changing the month to be written for each. " ?

Comment: The number of records for each month is more or less the same? If the number is diferent maybe that is the issue.

Are you committing after each run? Maybe giant transaction is slowing you down..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with this update statement. Then you don't need to write 12 statements and execute them in a row.

```
update 
   hondaacura 
set transdate1 = STR_TO_DATE(trxdate, '%d%b%Y');
```

For more info see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).